# Cannot load class org.jetbrains.idea.maven.dom.model.presentation.MavenProfilePresentationProvider error while running unit tests in windows IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am getting this below error when I try running unit tests from JUnit plugin in windows IntelliJ. I have the same project running fine in my mac.

> Cannot load class
> org.jetbrains.idea.maven.dom.model.presentation.MavenProfilePresentationProvider
> ( error: Illegal constant pool index 8457 for method signature in
> class file
> org/jetbrains/idea/maven/dom/model/presentation/MavenProfilePresentationProvider,
> classLoader=PluginClassLoader(plugin=PluginDescriptor(name=Maven,
> id=org.jetbrains.idea.maven, descriptorPath=plugin.xml,
> path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
> 2021.3.2\plugins\maven, version=213.6777.52, package=null, isBundled=true), packagePrefix=null, instanceId=92, state=active) )

Comment: Is this a version of IntelliJ including a Java runtime or did you configure it to run with your existing JVM?

Comment: Use the bundled Runtime in IntelliJ IDEA. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

Comment: I did this and it solved my issue. File > Settings > Build > Compiler > Java Compiler. I then changed the Project Bytecode Version to 11 and removed Per Module Bytecode Version entries.